# MDX query for getting the non null value records

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am new with MDX, Can any one of you help me out for the below queries?

[image]

1) From the above result set how can I eliminate rows which are having the null values in the column1 & column3 using below query.

```
WITH
MEMBER TotalPatientCnt as '[Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt]'
MEMBER PrevalencePercent as '([Measures].[PatientCnt]*1.00/[Measures].    [TotalPatientCnt])*100'

SELECT 
NON EMPTY {[DimCP_Population].[Dr Key].[Dr Key]}
ON rows, 
 { 
     [Measures].[PatientCnt] ,[Measures].[TotalPatientCnt]
     ,[Measures].[PrevalencePercent]

}
ON columns
FROM [StrategyCompanionDWCube]
WHERE 
(
    [DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20121231], 
    [DimCP_PCP].[PCP Key].&[124],
    [DimProduct].[Product Key].&[15],
    [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].&[1]
)
```

;

2) I have 3 dimensions & 3 measures respectively

```
[DimCP_PCP], [DimProduct], [DimHealthPlan]

pcpCnt, productCnt, HelahtPlanPatientCnt
```

I would like to build same `TotalPatientCnt` member based on type of dimension with parameter value, Hope needs to write case statement but i could not write case statement please help us on the below examples.

```
WITH MEMBER TotalPatientCnt as 
case 
when [DimProduct].[Product Key].&[if getting anymember] then
'[Measures].[productCnt]'
when [DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].&[if getting anymember] then
'[Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt]'
when [DimCP_PCP].[PCP Key].&[if getting anymember] then
'[Measures].[pcpCnt]'
```

If I get any parameter from `[DimCP_PCP]` for example [`DimCP_PCP].[PCP Key].&[124]` needs to show the TotalPatientCnt member like below

```
WITH MEMBER TotalPatientCnt as '[Measures].[pcpCnt]'
```

If I get any parameter from `[DimHealthPlan]` for example `[DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].&[1]` needs to show the `TotalPatientCnt` member like below

```
WITH MEMBER TotalPatientCnt as '[Measures].[HealthPlanPatientCnt]'
```

If I get any parameter from `[DimProduct]` example `[DimProduct].[Product Key].&[15]` needs to show the `TotalPatientCnt` member like below

```
WITH MEMBER TotalPatientCnt as '[Measures].[productCnt]'
```

Comment: That are two questions. I would suggest you delete the second, and post it as separate question.

Answer (score 4):

To answer your first question:

As `NON EMPTY` does not work for the rows here, as the second column is not empty for the records to exclude, you can use the rarely documented `HAVING` clause like this:

```
...
{[DimCP_Population].[Dr Key].[Dr Key]}
HAVING NOT IsEmpty([Measures].[PatientCnt])
   AND NOT IsEmpty([Measures].[PrevalencePercent])
ON rows
...
```

Comment: Hi Frank Thanks a lot. it is working as per my requirement. Request you to Could you please give solution on 2nd point

Comment: As I wrote in my comment to your question, to make searching and re-using answers more easy for others who might e. g. find your question and my answer via Google, I would suggest you edit your question to contain only a single question and an appropriate title, and put the second question into a separate question.

Comment: @FrankPl I also had similar problem , but as I am using topcount in my query, it is also considering null values in topcount, 
so if i have result  including null as 10, 20 , null, 30  
when I do topcount 3, it returns 10, 20 and when I do topcount 4 it returns 10, 20, 30.

means it is considering null value also in topcount.
please help

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
(
[DimAnchorDate].[Date Key].&[20121231], 
[DimCP_PCP].[PCP Key].&[124],
[DimProduct].[Product Key].&[15],
[DimHealthPlan].[Health Plan Key].&[1],
[Measures].[PatientCnt],
[Measures].[TotalPatientCnt]
,[Measures].[PrevalencePercent]
) On 0,
NON EMPTY {[DimCP_Population].[Dr Key].[Dr Key]}
ON 1       
FROM [StrategyCompanionDWCube]
```

OR

[Understand the difference between NON-EMPTY vs Nonempty()](https://sqldusty.com/2012/08/10/non-empty-vs-nonempty-to-the-death/)

Here, you might get your answer and to do clear concept of NULL and EMPTY